# Not able to view model information in detail page of ui5 application

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, hana

I am not able to view details for jobs in my detail view.Below is my code-
Component.js

```
 metadata : {
            rootView: "shell.app.poc.DWH.view.App",
            routing : {
                  config : {
                  routerClass : "sap.m.routing.Router",
                 //targetClass : "sap.m.routing.Targets",
                  viewType : "XML",
                  viewPath : "shell.app.poc.DWH.view",
                  controlId : "app",
                  controlAggregation : "pages",
                  transition: "slide"
                  },
                  routes: [
                            {
                              "pattern": "",
                              "name": "home",
                              "target": "home"
                            },
                            {
                              "pattern": "jobdetails/{jobPath}",
                              "name": "jobdetails",
                              "target": "jobdetails"
                            }
                          ],
                  targets : {
                      home:  {
                          viewPath : "shell.app.poc.DWH.view",
                          viewName : "App",
                         // viewLevel : 0
                      },
                      jobdetails:  {
                        viewPath : "shell.app.poc.DWH.view",
                        viewName: "Second",
                          //viewLevel : 1
                      }


                  }

                  }

},
```

My model is created from the JSON ouput of an xsjs as shown below-

```
 var oModel = new JSONModel("http://<host><ins>/shell/app/poc/DWH/test.xsjs");
     this.setModel(oModel);
```

Whenever I select a columnlist item of my table, I want to navigate to the detail page for that item.Below is the code for my master controller on the onPress event on each columnlist item -

```
 onPress : function (oEvent) {
          var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
          var oItem, oCtx;
          oItem = oEvent.getSource();
          oCtx = oItem.getBindingContext();
          var object = oCtx.getObject();
         //var path = this.getView().getElementBinding('records').sPath.substring(1)
          //var context = this.getView().getElementBinding('records').oContext;
            oRouter.navTo("jobdetails", {
                jobPath: oCtx.getProperty("bodsjobconcntrlid")
                //jobPath: oItem.getBindingContext('/records').getPath().substr(1)
            });
             console.log('oEvent.getSource: ' + oEvent.getSource());
            // console.log('path: ' + this.getView().getBindingContext().getPath());


                oCtx = oItem.getBindingContext();
                console.log('oEvent.getsource.getBindingContext: ' + oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext());
                        console.log('oCtx.getProperty: ' + oCtx.getProperty("bodsjobconcntrlid"));
                        console.log('object: ' + oCtx.getObject());
                        //console.log('context: ' + context);


        }
```

This is the code for my details controller-

```
 onInit: function () {
     var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);

     oRouter.getRoute("home").attachMatched(this._onObjectMatched, this);

    },
    _onObjectMatched: function (oEvent) {
        var oArgs, oView;
        oArgs = oEvent.getParameter("arguments");
        oView = this.getView();
        oView.bindElement({
            path : "/records(" + oArgs.bodsjobconcntrlid + ")"
        });

    },
```

This is my details view

I just get the label jobname but actually no value is present ...
This is the binding for my table-

```
items="{path: '/records'}"
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you bind ur view to this detail record

```
 oView.bindElement({
            path : "/records(" + oArgs.bodsjobconcntrlid + ")"
        });
```

if u have records under that detail record "/records(" + oArgs.bodsjobconcntrlid + ")",
you should use

```
items="{path: 'records'}"
```